# How to configure PyCharm to add leading periods to relative imports (PEP328)?

Tags: pycharm

When using the refactoring tools in PyCharm (for instance extracting a class), it adds statements like `from concept import Concept`, that I have to manually change to `from .concept import Concept` for [PEP328](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328)-compability. How can I configure PyCharm to add relative import statements correctly (with leading dots)?

Tried to look in Preferences, esp. under "Code Style", where there is a tab called "Imports", but couldn't find a setting for this. Under "Project Structure", I did set the `<package>` folder to be a "Sources" folder.

```
<project>
├── <package>
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── concept.py
│   ├── job.py
│   └── <etc..>.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── <etc..>.py
    ├── test_concept.py
    └── test_job.py
```